# "#exec cgi" command is ignored from html; same script runs as a "form post" command

Tags: linux, apache, cgi

Apache configuration files all appear correct; I've added the ExecCGI to the RootDirectory, although this file resides in the ScriptAlias directory so that shouldn't even be necessary.  I put a .htaccess file out there which is also probably not necessary.

This is a simple counter.cgi file - runs fine from the linux command line; runs fine called as a "method post" from an html file.  When I call it using "!exec cgi" it's as if it never happened - it's completely ignored.  There are no errors in any log files - the file is not executed.

Comment: Also... I have Includes as an Option. I've tried running as "#include virtual" as well as "#exec cgi" and in both cases the command DOES show up in the html source, it is simply ignored and not executed.

Answer (score 0):

I figured this out - my SSI configuration wouldn't process .html files.  Changed the httpd.conf file so that SSI includes were processed from .html files.  :)